# Postgres query should return an array of an array instead of an array of string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

**strong text**I have the following problem:
Given the two tables contacts and organisations :

```
WITH contacts(oe_id, name, email, person_id) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Mark', 'm.smith@test.nl', 19650728),
    (2, 'Tom', 't.b.smith@test.nl', 20010627), 
    (1, 'Frank', 'f.j.smith@test.nl', 20040709), 
    (3, 'Petra', 'p.ringenaldus@test.nl', 19700317), 
    (3, 'Paul', 'p.m.sprengers@test.nl', 19681006)),
organisations(oe_id, name) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Cardiology'), 
    (2, 'Neurology'), 
    (3, 'Dermatology'), 
    (4, 'Churgery'))
```

I want to get a table with 3 columns: the organisation name, the organisation id, and an array of contactpersons for that organisation.
Every array element is also an array with the data of the contact person.

First I created a table in which all contact columns are being aggregated into an array. One array per tuple row:

```
 WITH contacts(oe_id, name, email, person_id) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Mark', 'm.smith@test.nl', 19650728), 
    (2, 'Tom', 't.b.smith@test.nl', 20010627), 
    (1, 'Frank', 'f.j.smith@test.nl', 20040709), 
    (3, 'Petra', 'p.ringenaldus@test.nl', 19700317), 
    (3, 'Paul', 'p.m.sprengers@test.nl', 19681006)),
organisations(oe_id, name) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Cardiology'), 
    (2, 'Neurology'), 
    (3, 'Dermatology'), 
    (4, 'Churgery')),
contacts_aggregated(oe_id, cdata) AS (
    select oe_id, ARRAY[name, email, person_id::text] from contacts) 
select * from contacts_aggregated;
```

This result into:

```
 oe_id |                 cdata
-------+---------------------------------------
     1 | {Mark,m.smith@test.nl,19650728}
     2 | {Tom,t.b.smith@test.nl,20010627}
     1 | {Frank,f.j.smith@test.nl,20040709}
     3 | {Petra,p.ringenaldus@test.nl,19700317}
     3 | {Paul,p.m.sprengers@test.nl,19681006}
(5 rows)
```

Next step is to aggregate cdata (contact data) for each organisation id:

```
WITH contacts(oe_id, name, email, person_id) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Mark', 'm.smith@test.nl', 19650728), 
    (2, 'Tom', 't.b.smith@test.nl', 20010627), 
    (1, 'Frank', 'f.j.smith@test.nl', 20040709), 
    (3, 'Petra', 'p.ringenaldus@test.nl', 19700317), 
    (3, 'Paul', 'p.m.sprengers@test.nl', 19681006)),
organisations(oe_id, name) AS (VALUES
    (1, 'Cardiology'), 
    (2, 'Neurology'), 
    (3, 'Dermatology'), 
    (4, 'Churgery')),
contacts_aggregated(oe_id, cdata) AS (
    select oe_id, ARRAY[name, email, person_id::text] from contacts),
contacts_for_organisations(oe_id, contacts) AS (
    SELECT organisations.oe_id, array_agg(contacts_aggregated.cdata::text) 
    FROM organisations
    JOIN contacts_aggregated USING(oe_id) 
    GROUP BY oe_id)
SELECT * FROM contacts_for_organisations;
```

This results into the following:

```
 oe_id |                                      contacts
-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | {"{Mark,m.smith@test.nl,19650728}","{Frank,f.j.smith@test.nl,20040709}"}
     2 | {"{Tom,t.b.smith@test.nl,20010627}"}
     3 | {"{Petra,p.ringenaldus@test.nl,19700317}","{Paul,p.m.sprengers@test.nl,19681006}"}
(3 rows)
```

As you can see the result is an array. But its elements should also be an array. Instead of an array I get an imploded array as a string.

Wat I want is something like this:

```
 oe_id |                                      contacts
-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1 | {{Mark,m.smith@test.nl,19650728},{Frank,f.j.smith@test.nl,20040709}}
     2 | {{Tom,t.b.smith@test.nl,20010627}}
     3 | {{Petra,p.ringenaldus@test.nl,19700317},{Paul,p.m.sprengers@test.nl,19681006}}
(3 rows)
```

If I remove the cast to text array_agg(contacts_aggregated.cdata::text I get:

```
could not find array type for data type text[]
```

What am I forgetting/doing wrong?
Postgres: psql (9.2.24) and psql (9.6.10, server 9.2.24)

**If I run the code using a postgres client 9.6 on a postgres 9.6 server everyting works fine.**

Comment: I tested your GROUP BY query on PostgreSQL 11 and I got array of array as you want `{{Mark,m.smith@test.nl,19650728},{Frank,f.j.smith@test.nl,20040709}}` - both with "::text" cast and without it. So looks like your problem is really PG version specific.

Comment: It has to do with the version of the server on which it runs. The code will not work on postgres 9.2.

Comment: I strongly suggest to move your tasks to the latest PG 11 - we just did (abandoned all previous 9.5, 9.6 and 10 versions) and advantages are absolutely amazing.

Comment: I just moved to a higher version and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

I just moved to a higher postgres version and everything works fine now.

Comment: Postgres 9.2 [is not longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) anyway